# How to make motion to dynamic text in AS3?

Tags: flash

I want an animation with dynamic text because I want to load the text from files (with URLLoader).
If I modify it to symbol, its no longer loads the text from file.

Comment: It usually helps to give specific information about what you've tried and how it falls short.

Comment: If I had to guess, he/she hasn't adjust the code to account for the extra layer of logic. Note that if the Graphic symbol type works for the need, that shouldn't require any adjustment in the code.

Answer (score 0):

your textfield have to exist during all the animation
put it alone on a layer, and make it visible true/false when you need toi display it or not